# Checkbutton status with using list (tkinter python)

Tags: python, list, tkinter, status

I would like to get status of all defined checkbuttons by "for" function.
I have four checkbuttons and output is (off, off, off, off):

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But I need to have for example (off, on, on, off):

```
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

It looks like below code is geeting only staus from last "D" checkbuton and append to "buttons_status" list.

Any idea how to get status of all chcekbuttons?
Thanks in advance.

Here is a code:

```
from tkinter import *

names = ['A','B','C','D']
buttons_status = []

root = Tk()
for x in range(0,len(names)):
    checkbutton_input = IntVar()
    checkbutton = Checkbutton(root, text=str(names[x]),
    variable=checkbutton_input)
    checkbutton.grid(row=3, column=x)
    status = checkbutton_input.get()
    buttons_status.append(status)
root.mainloop()

print(buttons_status)
```

Comment: You're getting the status about a millisecond after you create the checkbutton. The user won't have had a chance to click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the actual IntVars to the list and call the get methods when you want to see the status. We would usually put a functionality like that in a function:

```
from tkinter import *

def get_all():
    return [x.get() for x in buttons_status]

names = ['A','B','C','D']
buttons_status = []

root = Tk()
for x in range(0,len(names)):
    checkbutton_input = IntVar()
    checkbutton = Checkbutton(root, text=str(names[x]), variable=checkbutton_input)
    checkbutton.grid(row=3, column=x)
    buttons_status.append(checkbutton_input)
root.mainloop()

print(get_all())
```

That said, it really sounds like what you need is a subclass. What's your overall goal here?

Comment: Novel. Overall goal: I will create GUI with checkbuttons. Based on which checkbutton user select next actions will be taken. To do this I need a list with checkbutton status.